Sampling rotations "uniformly"?
What is the name of the density over rotation matrices where the angle of rotation is uniformly distributed w.r.t to any subspace?
If we sample from $SO(n)$, angle is not uniform since resulting matrices have eigenvalues at angles close to 0 or $\pi$

We could instead sample 2D rotations by sampling $n$ angles uniformly from $(-\pi,\pi)$, and combining into a $2n\times 2n$ matrix using Jordan normal form, which creates uniform distribution of angles. Is there a name for this density?

negateFirstRow[A_] := {-A[[1, All]]}~Join~A[[2 ;;, All]];
sampleO[n_] := RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]];
sampleSO[n_] := 
  With[{mat = sampleO@n}, If[Det[mat] > 0, mat, negateFirstRow@mat]];

n = 4;
numSamples = 10000;
label = StringForm["Eigenvalues of SO(``)", n];
angles = Arg /@ Flatten[Table[Eigenvalues@sampleSO@n, {numSamples}]];
observedPlot = 
  Histogram[angles, {Pi/15}, PDF, PlotLabel -> label, 
   AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}];
predictedPlot = 
  Plot[(Cos[2 t] + 2)/(4 Pi), {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 3/(4 Pi)}, 
   PlotLegends -> {TraditionalForm[(Cos[2 t] + 2)/(4 Pi)]}];
Show[observedPlot, predictedPlot]

generalizedRotations[n_, thetas_] := 
  Module[{negateFirstRow, sampleO, blocks, realJordanform, p, R},
   blocks = Table[R[i] -> RotationMatrix[thetas[[i]]], {i, n/2}]; 
   realJordanform = 
    ArrayFlatten@(DiagonalMatrix[Array[R, n/2]] /. blocks); 
   p = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]]; 
   p\[Transpose] . realJordanform . p
   ];

n = 4;
numSamples = 10000;
randAngle := RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}];
randAngles := Table[RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}], n];
angles = 
  Arg /@ Flatten[
    Table[Eigenvalues@
      generalizedRotations[n, randAngles], {numSamples}]];
label = StringForm["Eigenvalues of ???(``)", n];

observedPlot = 
 Histogram[angles, {Pi/15}, PDF, PlotLabel -> label, 
  AxesLabel -> {"arg", "density"}]


I think the most natural measure to use would be the Haar measure. I'm afraid I don't remember what it tells about  the distribution of the rotation angle for $SO(3)$ (or angles in the case of $SO(4)$).

@JyrkiLahtonen angle is not uniform, this post talks about exact density https://mathoverflow.net/a/468494/7655

@JyrkiLahtonen also you can see predicted angle density and observed in my post, it's quite far from uniform

for a uniform distribution of eigenphases on the unit circle you can sample from $U(n)$ --- the circular unitary ensemble.

@CarloBeenakker Circular Unitary includes complex valued matrices, whereas example above gives uniform distribution of eigenphases with a real-valued matrix

Thanks for the link. I was worried/curious about how to sample $SO(n)$ uniformly with respect to the Haar measure.

@YaroslavBulatov For $SO(3)$, the simplest way to get the distribution you want is probably to randomly select an axis from the unit sphere, select an angle from a uniform distribution over $[0,\pi]$, and then generate the associated rotation matrix.

@BenGrossmann that's a simple rotation so it's sensitive to the choice of input vector. Looks like there's a way to make a complex rotation which is insensitive to choice of x, https://x.com/yaroslavvb/status/1826042105283883061?t=QNIQLHwjm98U9H52OCSYxA&s=19

@Yaroslav I'm not sure what you mean by "sensitive to the choice of input vector". Is the randomly generated axis the "input vector"? But sure, the approach you take in that colab is a reasonable way to go; you just need to add a 1-block in the case of odd $n$.

@YaroslavBulatov Your tweet (xeet?) seems to contradict your post: does Haar measure result in more angles close to $0$ or $\pi$, or does it result in more angles close to $\pi/2$? $\pi/2$ seems like the more intuitive result since, at the extremes, there is only one rotation by angle $0$ and there are "half as many" rotations by $\pi$ in 3D.

@BenGrossmann fixed the post, in one I looked at angle of rotation of random vector (close to pi/2) and in another I looked at distribution of angles of eigenvalues (distribution involving cosine given by Girko)

It may be helpful to note why the Haar measure for real orthogonal matrices does not give a rotationally invariant density of eigenvalues on the unit circle: since the matrices are real, the eigenvalues must come in complex conjugate pairs $e^{\pm i\phi}$. This constraint is not rotationally invariant.

I'm not sure about what exactly is your goal? In some sense you could think of $x$ and $Ax$ as independent unit vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, when the distribution of the angle in between (for large $n$) is heavily concentrated around $\pi/2$. Central limit theorem and all that. With a modest sized $n$, it won't be so extreme, but anyway.

@JyrkiLahtonen my goal is sample "small rotations" in a way that's 1) independent of dimension and 2) doesn't create unexpected biases. Uniform over angles seemed natural. Still need to find a reasonable generalization to rectangular matrices, right now people use this method, but it's not isotropic
